# How to enable mouse tracking on movement in QTabWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, mouseevent, qtwidgets

I have a QApplication in PyQt5 that tracks the mouse movement and updates a label with x & y coordinates. This works as expected when the mouse movement occurs within the main QDialog. However, when the mouse moves into a QTabWidget the label updating stops. It will resume again if I click (hold) and drag the mouse, but stops again once the left button is released. Why is this, and how can I change my code so the label continues to update when the mouse is moved into the QTabWidget?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyForm(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        x = event.x()
        y = event.y()
        text = "x: {0}, y: {1}".format(x, y)
        self.ui.labelTracking.setText(text)     

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(653, 450)
        Dialog.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(Dialog)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 0, 481, 451))
        self.tabWidget.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.labelTracking = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.labelTracking.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 131, 61))
        self.labelTracking.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.labelTracking.setText("")
        self.labelTracking.setObjectName("labelTracking")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("Dialog", "Test Tab"))


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyForm()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work if you enable mouse tracking on the widget inside the QTabWidget, and set its `mouseMoveEvent` to the one you defined.

```
class MyForm(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.tab.mouseMoveEvent = self.mouseMoveEvent
        self.show()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        pos = event.windowPos().toPoint()
        x = pos.x()
        y = pos.y()
        text = "x: {0}, y: {1}".format(x, y)
        self.ui.labelTracking.setText(text)
```

And in `Ui_Dialog` include `self.tab.setMouseTracking(True)`. `QMouseEvent.windowPos()` is used instead of `pos()` to get the coordinates relative to the window that received the event, as otherwise it would be relative to the tab widget when hovering over it.